# Oracle function returning large number of columns

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query that selects a large number of columns from a number of tables, nested select queries and functions.

First I was thinking about creating a view, but creating a view with IN parameters isn't really a common thing to do in oracle...
So I'm thinking of creating a function with this query in it, and return it as a table type. But then I would have to define an object type with as many variables, and either loop through each row or use bulk collect. But, with about 100 columns that my query returns, it would be a nightmare to define the object type.

Any suggestions how to approach this problem?

EDIT:
The solution I'm looking for would be to create a function using my query, and to be able to show results using SELECT my_function(:param1, :param2) from dual, or something like select * from table(my_function(:p1, :p2)). Is table type the only way to go, or is there an other simpler way to show the results from this function? 
Just to make it clear, creating a view wouldn't be very practical in this scenario.

EDIT2:
I guess that creating type record, for example: creating object type with all the columns defined, then creating table type and return it pipelined, is the only way to go if I want to retrieve those values using SELECT statement. Or there is an easier way to do this? Can a cursor based record be used to simplify this, and still retrieve values with a simple SELECT statement?

Comment: What's the situation where you want to call this procedure? Are you calling it from PL/SQL code? From a client program? From somewhere else? Thanks.

Comment: from a client program.

Comment: How many parameters are you talking about? If it's just a few, you might be able to add those as columns in your view, which means your view no longer needs "in" parameters.

Comment: Not many parameters, but used in many places as it's a fairly complex query. So views are definitively not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your function as a table (at least you wrote something like that) - you have to define type to be able to create pipelined function. Pipelined functions can be used in SQL statements as simple tables, so it fits your requirements. But again - if you really need pipelined function - you have to predefine type object and list all the "columns" there.
here is corresponding doc: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#CHDJEGHC

Im not sure you really need it.. 
I suppose you can return simple sys_refcursor from your function. In that case it isn't necessary to predefine any data structures outside your function. 
Here is simple example:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dummy
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  AS
    my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT 1 FROM dual;
    RETURN my_cursor;
  END get_dummy;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if my comment it misleading you.
You can have a ref cursor. Then have single variable that has cursor's %rowtype. Then these columns can be accessed as rowtype_variable.column_name(loop_int).

If this is any closure what you expect, then I can help you more. Else elaborate your problem.

Comment: I think this might help, one rowtype variable with all the columns in it might be the way to go... googling examples at the moment to see if it fits...

Comment: @Alex You didn't specified your programming language. For Java see e.g. _Using Cursor Variables_ in [Enhancing the Application: Advanced JDBC Features](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28765/addfunc.htm). JDBC doesn't support PL/SQL records.

Comment: don't worry about the external program. if it works with BEGIN call_my_function_with_many_rows(); END; - it will work from the client app. all I'm focusing now is the way for my function to return a large number of rows, without using object type defining all those rows if possible...